# JWT Security with IP Addresses

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, jwt

I am building a Web Application using Angular 2 and the backend service built in ASP.NET Core Web API.

For authentication, I am thinking of using `JWT` and storing the token in a Secure HttpOnly Cookie.

For extra security, I am also thinking of capturing the IP Address for the user on the initial login and on each request after the initial login, revoking the token if the IP Address changes.

So the questions I have are:

- Is this extra level of security worth it?
- Will there be any problems with the IP check I am thinking of using?  Based what I know about networking, I don't think an IP Address will legitimately change between request.  Even if it does, I think it would be very rare.  However I am not going to pretend I know enough about networking to confirm that.

### Edit 1

(In response to an answer).

Thank you for answering my question. I have responded to a few of your responses.

> My initial thought was that using JWT in a cookie to connect to an API is not the typical use case, why don't you use a standard MVC app then, but that's not your question and actually it's equally secure as long as the token is in a secure, httponly cookie (and of course the implementation is correct). It's just a bit unusual I think.

I am not sure why you consider using cookies this way unusual?

Is it because most of the time cookies are used for session state?  I personally think storing a token in a secure cookie instead of keeping the token in a `http` header or local storage should be a very typical use case because of how much more secure it is.  Unless I am missing something?

So I guess I will ask what is the disadvantage of doing it this way?

> It depends. If you are worried about session theft, probably yes. If you keep the token in an httponly cookie (protected against xss), that's more secure than a token anywhere else, but still, your threat model may show different threats and validate your concern. The usual problem is you can't do this, see below.

This application will be dealing with a lot of `PPI` information so I do have a concern on token theft.

> Most probably, there will be problems. It depends on your users, how and from where they use your application. If they use mobile devices, IP addresses will change a lot and such a solution is out of the question. If they are corporate users in a company internal network, it can be feasible. Anything inbetween is a gray area. A typical home user will have their IP changed once in a while, most people get dynamic IP allocation from their internet providers. An IP lease typically lasts a few weeks (at least where I live), but ISPs can configure it any way they want, it can be a day or even shorter.

My impression with IP address lease renew is majority of the time the client gets the same IP address. However I should not make that assumption I suppose?

However I can see this can be more of a problem with mobile devices.  Some of the clients will be on the road often so this is a good point you have made that can become a problem.

> One typical solution you can choose to do is offer this option on the login screen. If a user chooses to use IP address validation, he opts for greater security but accepts the fact that sometimes he may have to log in again. Or he can choose lower security with his session being more stable. Whether it's worth to explain this to your users is I think a business decision.

Never thought about giving the client an option which does sound like a good idea.

### Edit 2

(In response to an answer).

> Also I'm not sure whether your JWT only has a session id or if your server is stateless and all session data is in the JWT. In the first case, you don't even need the JWT, you could just pass the session id as normal, and standard .Net MVC does that for you. If it's session data too, JWTs are unencrypted by default, so session contents will be visible to endusers, which may or may not be a problem. (And a JWT is protected from tampering by its signature, so it's only about confidentiality, not integrity). Storing session data in the JWT and the JWT in the cookie may also face cookie size issues, depending on your target browsers.

My backend ASP.NET Core Web API will be stateless. The decision has already been made to use `Angular` so discussing is a moot point.

> As for why I think using a JWT this way is a little unusual: I think JWTs are mostly used when tokens need to be passed to different URLs (to different services). For this purpose, httpOnly cookies are obviously inadequate because of the same origin rule. If you can afford using httpOnly cookies, you could just store your session info on the server side.

A much as I would like to discuss the above topic because my solution *could* be flawed, I think the powers that be may close this post for getting off topic?

Might be more appropriate to ask a new question targeted toward the above subject?

> As for lease renews resulting in the same IP: Well, they don't always. It depends on your business case, but some ISPs give you IPs only for a short time. If it's ok for your users to get logged out once in a while, then it may be ok for wired (home) users. And it is definitely a big problem with mobile devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My initial thought was that using JWT in a cookie to connect to an API is not the typical use case, why don't you use a standard MVC app then, but that's not your question and actually it's equally secure as long as the token is in a secure, httponly cookie (and of course the implementation is correct). It's just a bit unusual I think.

On to the point, your question is very valid as is your concern about problems.

> Is this extra level of security worth it?

It depends. If you are worried about session theft, probably yes. If you keep the token in an httponly cookie (protected against xss), that's more secure than a token anywhere else, but still, your threat model may show different threats and validate your concern. The usual problem is you can't do this, see below.

> Will there be any problems with the IP check I am thinking of using?

Most probably, there will be problems. It depends on your users, how and from where they use your application. If they use mobile devices, IP addresses will change a lot and such a solution is out of the question. If they are corporate users in a company internal network, it can be feasible. Anything inbetween is a gray area. A typical home user will have their IP changed once in a while, most people get dynamic IP allocation from their internet providers. An IP lease typically lasts a few weeks (at least where I live), but ISPs can configure it any way they want, it can be a day or even shorter.

So reality is if you have a normal, usual userbase, you will most probably run into problems.

One typical solution you can choose to do is offer this option on the login screen. If a user chooses to use IP address validation, he opts for greater security but accepts the fact that sometimes he may have to log in again. Or he can choose lower security with his session being more stable. Whether it's worth to explain this to your users is I think a business decision.

**Update** in response to Edit 1 :)

As for why I think using a JWT this way is a little unusual: I think JWTs are mostly used when tokens need to be passed to different URLs (to different services). For this purpose, httpOnly cookies are obviously inadequate because of the same origin rule. If you can afford using httpOnly cookies, you could just store your session info on the server side. Also I'm not sure whether your JWT only has a session id or if your server is stateless and all session data is in the JWT. In the first case, you don't even need the JWT, you could just pass the session id as normal, and standard .Net MVC does that for you. If it's session data too, JWTs are unencrypted by default, so session contents will be visible to endusers, which may or may not be a problem. (And a JWT is protected from tampering by its signature, so it's only about confidentiality, not integrity). Storing session data in the JWT and the JWT in the cookie may also face cookie size issues, depending on your target browsers.

As for lease renews resulting in the same IP: Well, they don't always. It depends on your business case, but some ISPs give you IPs only for a short time. If it's ok for your users to get logged out once in a while, then it may be ok for wired (home) users. And it is definitely a big problem with mobile devices.

Comment: Please view my responses above.

Comment: Modified my answer @Michael

Comment: Modified my answer once more.

Comment: Oh well, instant post on mobile and no delete , sorry. :) So, in short: 1. JWT is secure if implemented correctly, but it would be simpler with MVC standard sessions, and see next 2. JWT contents are not encrypted, session contents are visible to users! 3. Checking ip for the session will result in logouts, especially on mobile, but sometimes on wired too; this can be optional for a user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with JWT and IP. When the user logs in. Capture the IP for the length of the session. At every login Capture IP then use that to validate the Token is from the owner who started the session. If another IP hits the system. force a revalidate and new token.  IP+JWT+Password = login. If you had mobile apps that required 1 login and always remember the login. User never has to enter login again. Then cache the userid\password in the application {securely} and then resend it automatically when the IP changes.  JWT is secure when using SSL  [Difference between SSL and JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281438/difference-between-ssl-and-jwt)

Comment: How would you cache the user/pass securely? Its not a good idea to keep in memory user/password.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving this, but lately I have been thinking a lot about encryption and security and thought of something (that I guess is pretty similar to what HTTPS does)

When user logs in, the server responds with a normal greeting (user info, JWT and whatever other data you need to pass) + you will pass a public key

Have a backend that supports any asymmetric encryption method (I like RSA) and have your front (also needs to run the same encryption method) end receive the public key, encrypt the data, and send it to the server with every subsequent request.

If any of the data that the user needs to provide changes, revoke.

You can even keep track of a clock, if its off by too much, revoke.

For extra layer, have the client transmit a public key on login/signup and boom, hermetic comms like a hazmat suit.